# Hardcode additonal validator in chainspec

Tags: substrate-node-template

I was referring the substrate documentation on [preparing a local relay chain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/) . The documentation has provided a sample plain chain spec with two validators Alice and Bob. I need to hardcode an additional validator. I think I need to add something like below in the keys array in the chain spec but I'm not exactly sure what would the values for beefy, granpa etc would be.

```
            [
          "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc",
          "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc",
          {
            "grandpa": "5GoNkf6WdbxCFnPdAnYYQyCjAKPJgLNxXwPjwTh6DGg6gN3E",
            "babe": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
            "im_online": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
            "para_validator": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
            "para_assignment": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
            "authority_discovery": "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty"
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Within your [`chain_spec.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/bin/node-template/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L130) file you can find the types for those keys.

In the linked example we have

```rust
initial_authorities: Vec<(AuraId, GrandpaId)>,
```

In you case you will just need to declare the type for each key that you are using.

Another example with more keys defined can be found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/7035034710ecb9c6a786284e5f771364c520598d/substrate/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L248)

```rust
/// Helper function to create RuntimeGenesisConfig for testing.
pub fn testnet_genesis(
    initial_authorities: Vec<(
        AccountId,
        AccountId,
        GrandpaId,
        BabeId,
        ImOnlineId,
        AuthorityDiscoveryId,
        MixnetId,
    )>,
    initial_nominators: Vec<AccountId>,
    root_key: AccountId,
    endowed_accounts: Option<Vec<AccountId>>,
) -> RuntimeGenesisConfig {
// snip
```

Comment: I am not sure if i understand this. I am referreing to the [sample plain chain spec](https://docs.substrate.io/assets/tutorials/relay-chain-specs/plain-local-chainspec.json/) that has been provided in the documentation. I dont' think that this plain chainspec which is a json file is genereated from the node template for this specific example nor is the plain file generated from chain spec of the [release i am using](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v1.0.0/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L1185). Also i am not completely sure of what the type for keys would be .

Comment: I also checked the [chain spec](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L1193]) in the polkadot sdk.
I think that in chain_spec.rs rococo_local_tesnet is configured for two validator and i would have to make some code changes to use one more validator.

Comment: And this is what they mean by hardcoding an additional validator and generating chainspec  or i can use wococo since it is configured for more than two validators but then again i would need a wasm binary to generate the chainspec for wococo.